# where/how do i find the file for 'sound' of 'system settings'?

Tags: sound, system-settings

I need to find the file for 'sound'(sound settings) of 'systems settings' 
I need to know that files command
and use that command to make a separate line for 'sound' in the 'sound and video' section of 'main menu'

I use gnome in ubuntu 12.04 lts

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .desktop file on my Gnome3 shell has this command:

```
gnome-control-center sound
```